# How to change all values in a field in one operation?

Tags: qgis

I am setting up a couple of shapefiles with text x, text y, text rotation and text size fields in order to utilize the labeling toolbar where I can move and rotate labels. I would like the values for all the records in the text size field to be 8. Is there a way to change them all at once, so they don't have to be done individually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the field calculator to create a new integer field (or update an existing one). Just set your expression to be:

```
8
```