# I would like to change all the values in a attribute field to the same text

Tags: qgis

So I recieved a great answer to this question, [How to change all values in a field in one operation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44252/how-to-change-all-values-in-a-field-in-one-operation), although I need some further information. I would like to change the values in the entire field to the font name that I would like it to be. When I type in the font name, it claims that it is an invalid expression. Another example of what I would like to do is change all values of another column to half, related to the vertical alignment.

Comment: Are you putting the text in quote marke e.g. "Times New Roman"?

Comment: Quotes didn't work, but apostrophes did. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the text in single quotes ' '. Double quotes "  " are reserved for field names.

Comment: How would you approach this, though, if the text you needed to insert contained an apostrophe/single quote in the text?

Comment: I have not tested it, but doubling the quotes (`''` or `""`) might help.